# Organizing beans in ServletContext and ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring-webmvc+spring-security application and I encountered a problem with bean injection. First of all, `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` and `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` are all defined in `web.xml`, servlet context is called `servlet-context.xml` and application context -- `application-context.xml`.

Now, the problem arises when I create my service, which uses `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. If I create this bean in `application-context.xml`, no bean is found of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` type. If, however, I put it in `servlet-context.xml`, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is found, I can use my service in Controllers, but I cannot use it in other services, created in `application-context.xml`.

My question is how to organize bean creation in such application configuration. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

**Edit:** when application is started with a specific profile, a filter is added to the filter chain, which allows you to mock API calls. This filter is defined in application context, because that's where spring security is defined. It also needs to access a service, which can provide a list of all request mappings and our custom permissions associated with them (and no, they don't translate to spring roles that well). However, this service needs to be defined in servlet context, because it needs to access `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

**Edit #2**: I produced a MWE (probably shoud be Minimal *Not* Working Example?) here: https://github.com/guilty/separate-spring-contexts.

Now, there's an `ExampleController` and `CoreService`. They are both created in separate contexts and need to access `MappedUrlsService`, which in turn expects `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean to be accessible. Depending on where you actually create the `MappedUrlsService` bean, you either get that `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean is not found, or `MappedUrlsService` bean is not found. Here's a stack trace of when `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is not found:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.github.guilty.spring.service.CoreServiceImpl#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.github.guilty.spring.service.MappedUrlsService com.github.guilty.spring.service.CoreServiceImpl.mappedUrlsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.github.guilty.spring.service.MappedUrlsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:446)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.github.guilty.spring.service.MappedUrlsService com.github.guilty.spring.service.CoreServiceImpl.mappedUrlsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.github.guilty.spring.service.MappedUrlsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.github.guilty.spring.service.MappedUrlsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 65 more
```

Run the example with `mvn jetty:run`. Note, that `Java 7` and `Maven` are required to run it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your use case. Can you post the full stack trace of your missing bean exception as well as the relevant parts of your config?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have provided a stack trace and an application demonstrating my issue. See my 2nd edit of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

RequestMappingHandlerMapping is designed to be used in the controller layer only (typically with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`) so should only be in your servlet-context.xml

Is there a reason you need this in your service layer?

Comment: I don't think the "why" is important here. Basically, it would be nice if a non-magical solution existed that merged both servlet context and application context into one.

Comment: @PauliusK. There is, but you don't want to do that. You should try to use Spring as intended.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I updated my question specifying when my problem actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

A `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is created in the context of `DispatcherServlet` which can access beans defined in the root context (application-context.xml) but not the other way around. You could however define a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean in the root context. Spring MVC should pick that up with no problem. But it really does not make sense outside the servlet context.

Comment: This approach does not seem to be working. I extended RequestMappingHandlerMapping and put my bean in the root context. Problem is, when it gets created, it queries context for handler methods, defined in `@Controller`s, and they are not yet created, because they are defined in servlet context. Relevant piece of code can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L117-126)

Comment: Ah yes. I did not think that through well enough. Since you need beans from the dispatcherservlet's context why wouldn't you define the filter bean there?

Comment: because spring security is configured in core context. It should be defined in core context, because `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` creates it and `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` is created inside it. I wouldn't want to create `DelegatingFilterProxy` manually.

Comment: The point is. You cannot refer to beans in the servlet context from within the root context. You really should move the service and spring security to the servlet context.

Answer (score 0):

Well I won't discuss the why of your bean organization, but only the how.

You can inject beans from root context in beans from servlet context but not the opposite, as servlet context is created as root context as its parent.

IMHO it is really bad design to have a bean in service layer depending on a bean in controller layer, and in real world you should try to avoid it. but let's keep on.

I suggest you to create a relay bean in controller package and servlet contex and leave `MappedUrlsService` in service package and root context. Then you inject the service in relay, but in reality write a pointer to relay in the service :

```
public class MappedUrlsRelayImpl {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    // all the stuff that is presently in MappedUrlsServiceImpl
    // ...

    @Autowired
    private void setMappedUrlsServiceImpl (MappedUrlsServiceImpl serviceImpl) {
        serviceImpl.setMappedUrlsRelayImpl(this);
    }
}
```

The your service bean is simply :

```
public class MappedUrlsServiceImpl implements MappedUrlsService {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    private MappedUrlsRelayImpl relay;

    @Override
    public Set<String> getMappedUrls() {
        return relay.getMappedUrls();
    }

    public void setMappedUrlsRelayImpl(MappedUrlsRelayImpl relay) {
        this.relay = relay;
    }
}
```

It is pretty ugly because a service depends on a controller layer class and I reverse a Spring injection of dependancy, but it works.

To be complete the beans in servlet context

```
<bean class="com.github.guilty.spring.controller.ExampleController" />
<bean class="com.github.guilty.spring.controller.MappedUrlsRelayImpl" />
```

and in root context

```
<bean class="com.github.guilty.spring.service.CoreServiceImpl" />
<bean class="com.github.guilty.spring.service.MappedUrlsServiceImpl" />
```